# Remove 'Files' property on User Profiles app in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, user-profile, sharepoint-userprofile

I am trying to remove the 'Files' property on the User Profiles app in SharePoint. I go to the central adminstration for SharePoint in the Office Admin Center and then click on the 'user profiles' tab, then under People go to 'Manage User Properties'. However I do not find a property for 'Files'. I want to remove this as even though it only shows files which are publicly shared and will only show personal OneDrive files to pertaining to the logged in Current User, I would prefer to have this feature hidden.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no property called 'Files' in the User profile service application. You can try to hide this button with css. If you want to restrict upload of documents, you may decrease quota limit for my sites.